# Numpy Int Array to HEX and then to String Conversion PYTHON

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy

I have couple of questions

Say I have a numpy array

```
a = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,31])

a0 = a[0]
a1 = a[1]
a2 = a[2]
a3 = a[3]
a4 = a[4]
a5 = a[5]


print hex(a4), hex(a5)
```

gives me

```
   0x4L 0x1F
```

same for a0, a1, a2, a3,a5. I know the L is because of the numpy array.

Now how would I get 0x04 and not 0x4.

My required outcome is

```
'0x1F0403020100'
```

My required answer should start with 0x -- the hex values of a5, a4, a3, a2, a1, a0 - without the OX. The required output is a string. I can do the bit manipulation, if I have the zero. But not without it.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I find your question very unclear on multiple points. Is `0x0403020100` supposed to be hex for your entire array? That most certainly doesn't work like that... That number is 17230332160... And `0x4`, `0x04`, `0x000004` are all the same number: 4 (in both hexadecimal end decimal). [You might be facing an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: May I ask why you want to put the hex values of multiple numbers next to each other, after a single `0x`? I'm pretty sure you don't *need* that. I mean, it's as if you wanted to represent your array in decimal as `43210`.

Comment: I am writing a GUI application where I am interacting with an MCU through serial communication. The person who coded the MCU, declared a variable in that format. So when I read from MCU, I read the data as I pointed out in the question, Now I have to display in the required format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**

```
("0x" + ("{:0>2x}" * len(a))).format(*tuple(a[::-1]))
```

---

**Explanation:**

- Multiply string `"{:0>2x}"` a number of times equal to `len(a)`, i.e. do `"{:0>2x}" * len(a)`. This will create the following string:

  ```
  '{:0>2x}{:0>2x}{:0>2x}{:0>2x}{:0>2x}{:0>2x}'
  ```

  `{:0>2x}` used inside  a string can later be formated using the `.format` method, resulting in a translation of an int into a hexadecimal string, of width 2, where any padding is done with `0`.
  Multiplying by the length of the array means you can create that many hex-formatted arguments.
- Concatenate / prefix this string by `"0x"`
- Reverse your array, since you want it reversed, by doing `a[::-1]`
- Put the reversed array into a tuple, i.e. `tuple(a[::-1])`.
- Expand this tuple using * syntax to make it into method arguments, i.e. `*tuple(a[::-1])`
- Now you can use the expanded tuple as an argument to the `.format` method, on the concatenated string you created containing the custom formatting the correct number of times.

Result:

```
>>> ("0x" + ("{:0>2x}" * len(a))).format(*tuple(a[::-1]))
'0x1f0403020100'
```

PS. If you prefer capital hex strings, replace `x` with `X`, i.e.:

```
>>> ("0x" + ("{:0>2X}" * len(a))).format(*tuple(a[::-1]))
'0x1F0403020100'
```

Comment: Hahahah. In my defense, it's just that python can be ugly this way sometimes :p

Comment: @AndrasDeak though, now that you said it, I *am* itching to remove all spaces from that line ... xD

Answer (score 2):

What you really want to do is to store your array in a single number by shifting each element of the array by a certain (8) amount of bits:

```
>>> a = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,31])
>>> hex(sum([ai*256**i for i,ai in enumerate(a)]))
'0x1f0403020100'
```

But for this to work, you need to be sure that your array elements are at most 255. That's entirely up to you to keep/check. You should consider using an `ndarray` of `dtype` `np.uint8`, that way there's no chance for you to mangle up the data in your array (since you can't have overflow in your array).

Comment: It did not work. The answer I got after executing your code is 0xb900L. I am using Python 2.7

Comment: @Josh on python 2.7.6 I get `'0x1f0403020100L'`. Are you sure you copied it properly?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this workaround. An element wise `hex` conversion and a later `join`.   `'0x'` is added to the start of the string:

```
>>> a = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,31])
>>> '0x' + ''.join('{:02X}'.format(i) for i in reversed(a))
'0x1F0403020100'
```

Answer (score 0):

For python 3.5+:

```
'0x'+a.astype(np.uint8)[::-1].tobytes().hex().upper()
```